# OpenCV 2.2 image processing

Tags: opencv

I have to make an application which recognize road signs. I saw that in OpenCV folder there are some XML files for facial recognition but I do not know what that numbers in the XML represents or how they obtained those values. I need to understand this so as I can do my own XML files for road sign recognition.

Comment: as far as i understand you need to use haar trainer to create your own haar cascades xml file. this link might help more http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining/document.html

Comment: ziziana, Kunal:  If kunal's answer solves your problem, give it as the answer and accept it, and close the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know much about OpenCV, anyhow I have completed my Final Year Project on Face Recognition using neural networks. Basically I used an algorithm to extract the Facial Portion from a given image. Thereafter I fed that new image (containing only the face) to a neural network that I developed using Matlab. After rigorous improvements, it was a success and by using the Simulation Feature of Matlab it was possible to precisely identify the individual.

Therefore I strongly recommend that you follow the same technique in carrying out this task.
I managed to find some interesting articles related to this topic, [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~fuh/personal/RoadSignDetectionfromComplexBackgrounds.pdf), [here](http://crit2007.bartlab.org/Dr.%20Jackrit%27s%20Papers/ney/1.TRAFFIC_SIGN_Lorsakul_ISR.pdf) , [here](http://robesafe.com/personal/sotelo/ETFASenales2003.pdf)  and [here](http://e-archivo.uc3m.es/bitstream/10016/7110/1/road_escalera_TIE_1997.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two steps:

1. detection step
2. recognition step

for the detection, I suggest you to use cascade classifier that is included with opencv. It's robust and more quick than that of haar trainer. By this step you train the traffic signs to be detected. I found this [tutorial](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) that may help you how to prepare your training stuff

by this step you detect your signs . it may detect you some additional false objects in the image, for these undesired objects you can eliminate them by some processing like ratio, or color , or even by adding some negative images.

- for the recognition I suggest you to use exactly the [opencv's tutorial dedicated for face recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) 
  here you don't need a lot of modification..